Load 1000 files into bigquery table
I have 9000 and more avro files, when I try to load it is failing due to  “Resource exceed during query execution”
Bq load —source_formar=AVRO —replace dataset.table gs://abc/*.avro
I tried max_rows_per_request but not working
any other way to upload 5000 files
